# Java Timer Consumes CPU

Tags: java, timer, cpu-usage

```
//I call the methods under the init
{
  showdate();
  showtime();
}

void showdate() 
{
  Date d = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat a = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
  date.setText(a.format(d));
}

void showtime()
{
  new Timer(0, new ActionListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      Date d = new Date();
      SimpleDateFormat a = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
      time.setText(a.format(d));
    }
  }).start();
}
```

This code is consuming 80% of my CPU and I really need to show the time and date on my forms.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell the timer to wait some amount of time between invoking your method?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: A delay time of 0 is unrealistic and will serve no purpose other than to burn CPU cycles. Try a more realistic value such as 13 or 15, or even longer if it is OK with program function.

Comment: You are only displaying seconds so every second or 1000 milli-seconds might be enough. `0` means as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delay time of 0 is unrealistic and will serve no purpose other than to burn CPU cycles. Try a more realistic value like 13 or 15, or even longer if it is OK with program function.